# java.util.logging - Add a prefix at runtime

Tags: java, logging

I have a Java web application running on Tomcat that interprets and runs other mini Java applications (Beanshells). Both the main app and the mini apps use the default java.util.logging. The main app includes a logging.properties file that enables writing logs to a file separate from the main Tomcat logs.

At runtime within the mini app interpreter, I want to be able to place the current mini app name at the front of every log statement. Is there a way to do this with default java.util.logging?

I have attempted to use a system property called app.name in the format string inside logging.properties, setting and clearing the property at runtime, but no dice - nothing is logged before the rest of the string. Here's the logging.properties file for the main webapp:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level=INFO
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory=${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix=apprunner.
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding=UTF-8
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=${app.name} %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n
```

Inside the evalJava function inside com.apprunner.App:

```
logger.info("### BEGIN JAVA EXECUTION ###");
System.setProperty("app.name", ui_object_name);
logger.info(System.getProperty("app.name"));
```

Resulting logs in apprunner.[date].log:

```
Jul 19, 2023 4:09:29 PM com.apprunner.App evalJava
INFO: ### BEGIN JAVA EXECUTION ###
Jul 19, 2023 4:09:29 PM com.apprunner.App evalJava
INFO: testapp/app/testapp.java
```

Answer (score 0):

> At runtime within the mini app interpreter, I want to be able to place the current mini app name at the front of every log statement. Is there a way to do this with default java.util.logging?

One issue with `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` system property or logging property is that it is read and set once when the class is loaded and is forever that value.

To build something dynamic you have to write your own [java.util.logging.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) or find a 3rd party formatter:

```
public class AppFormatter extends SimpleFormatter {
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        return System.getProperty("app.name") + " " + super.format(record);
    }
}
```

Then in your configuration file you have to replace the use of SimpleFormatter with full qualified name of your `AppFormatter`.